# Problems accessing length property in array

Tags: ember.js

In [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/etines/2) this is not getting updated:

```
<span class="badge">{{controllers.nodesIndex.length}} records</span>
```

In the `nodes` template, but this is working:

```
<h2>Nodes list: {{this.length}}</h2>
```

In the `nodes/index` template. What is wrong with `{{controllers.nodesIndex.length}}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed putting 'needs' in your NodesController

```
App.NodesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['nodesIndex']
});
```

Updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/esevox/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks! I am doing so many tests, tests of tests, jsbins and jsfiddles that I am in a state of permanent confussion! :(